# Why are my JavaScript variables not persisting across functions?

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, document, element

I have the following JavaScript in my HTML page referencing an HTML form on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var myForm = document.myForm;

function validateForm() {
    if (myForm.myInput == "")
        alert("Please input some text.");

        return false;
    }

    myForm.submit();
}

function showFormInput() {
    myForm.reset();

    document.getElementById('myInput').style.display = 'inline';
}

//-->
</script>

...

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="..." method="post">
    <input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" value="" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```

Both functions are throwing an exception when trying to access the variable `myForm`, saying that "myForm is null or not an object". Why is this occurring?

**UPDATE:** One thing I think I'm gathering from this is that global variables should generally be used for string literals - not elements in the DOM. I"m going to go forward with this, and use element variables sparingly, and only after the DOM has been loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What browser are you using?

IN general you should never use `document.*` access.  This is an MS-IE convention.  Instead, use

```
var myForm = document.getElementById( 'myForm' ) ;
var myInput = document.getElementById( 'myInput' ) ;

if( myInput.value == '' )
{
    // its empty!
}
```

As outis noted, either put your script block at the bottom of your page, or use the `onload` event of <body> tag, like this

```
<script>
function go()
{
    alert( "The DOM has been assembled and can be accessed.. nOW!!!" ) ;
    var myForm = document.getElementById( 'myForm' ) ; // ...
}
</script>
<body onload="go() ;">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to avoid document.* from now on.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is in `document.myForm`. You may want to use:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
```

---

**UPDATES**: The other answers caught another couple of issues:

[As bobobobo noted in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758210/why-are-my-javascript-variables-not-persisting-across-functions/2758250#2758250), you should use `document.getElementById()` for `myForm.myInput` as well. In addition [outis caught another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758210/why-are-my-javascript-variables-not-persisting-across-functions/2758587#2758587) as you should place your `<script>` block near the end of your HTML document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Otherwise your script will execute before the form gets inserted in the DOM.

Answer (score 7):

If the sample is representative of the page, the the form "myForm" doesn't exist when the script is evaluated. In addition to using `document.getElementById` (or `document.forms.formName`), you'll need to delay setting `var myForm` until after the form element is processed or, [better yet](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad), pass the form as an argument to the functions rather than using a global variable.

Comment: I thought this might be the problem. It makes sense. Thank you.